# Inconsistent property name casing in generated JsonResult

Tags: jquery, vb.net, json, caching, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been scratching my head on this for a while now and have decided to let the SO community take a crack at it...

I have a few actions that respond to POSTs from the client side that do simple tasks and return a `JsonResult` built from an anonymous class with a simple Boolean "Success" property if it succeeds, or returns a `PartialViewResult` with `ModelState` errors if the action was unsuccessful:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function UpdateHeader(ByVal header As XmlReturnHeader) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim updated As Integer = TaxRepository.XmlReturnHeader.Update(header)
        If updated = 1 Then
            Return Json(New With {.Success = True}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End If
    End If
    Return PartialView("Maintenance/Header", header)
End Function
```

On the client side, the code is equally as simple. I want to see if the result has a `Success` property, make sure that it was really `true` and then go from there:

```
$.post('<%= Url.Action("UpdateHeader") %>', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
    if (data.Success && data.Success === true) {
        $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
        $('#edit').dialog('close');
    } else { // result must be the HTML
        $('#edit').html(data);
    }
});
```

However, I ran into issues testing. The `data` object I receive from the callback function always looks like this:

```
{ success: true }
  ^
```

The `s` in `success` is lower-case, and because JS is case-sensitive, I have a problem.

The strange part is if I change the VB.NET code to

```
Return Json(New With {.Garbage = True}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet),
```

I will receive

```
{ Garbage: true }
```

If I change it back to `New With { .Success = True }`, I again see the lower-case `s`.

I am using IIS and IE9 for testing. I feel like the response is somehow being cached. There are other places in the application where I use a lower-case "success" as a property in an anonymous `JsonResult` parameter. Perhaps IIS is caching a response from a previous GET or POST request?

**[Update]**

To test the response caching theory, I changed my code to:

```
Return Json(New With {.Success = True, .Random = DateTime.Now.Ticks},
   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

This caused the correct response to be received on the client side. Great. But what the heck was going on before? I thought POSTs were exempt from caching? Or is that only requests and not Responses?

How can I avoid this in the future?

**[Update]**

One other tidbit: I do globally disable caching my requests via jQuery, but I do not have any `OutputCacheAttribute`s or any such "no-cache" mechanism employed on the server side. I quicky slapped `<OutputCache(NoStore:=True, Duration:=0, VaryByParam:="*")>` on the entire controller, removed the `.Random` property from the JSON, but still received `{ success: true }`.

I have go so far as to recycle application pools, remove Temporary .NET Files, and clear browser cache, and the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen it, you may want to take a look at the following article on Output Caching in ASP.net MVC: http://juristr.com/blog/2012/10/output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/

According to the article, the default response headers include:

```
Cache-Control:private
```

Which means that IE *can* cache the response in a private cache. The article offers three options for disabling caching of these requests: disabling it globally on the server (which I don't recommend for client performance reasons), writing a custom global action filter (which has the same result), or adding an attribute to your controller action called OutputCache:

```
<OutputCache(Duration:=0)>
```

While the jQuery setting should perform a similar function, it may not garner the same result. Try this and see if it works.